# Error install exchange 2016 coexistence with exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2016, exchange-migration, exchange-server

When installing exchange 2016.

Error: **step 7 of 14 mailbox role: Transport service**

```
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 

          if ( ($server -eq $null) -and ($RoleIsDatacenter -ne $true) )
          {
            Update-RmsSharedIdentity -ServerName $RoleNetBIOSName
          }
        ": "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.DataValidationException: Database is mandatory in UserMailbox.
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.Save(ADObject instanceToSave, IEnumerable`1 properties, Boolean bypassValidation)
   )".
```

Checking in exchange 2010. I have the following error, in the following [Blog FederateMailbox](https://www.techieshelp.com/exchange-2013-update-rmssharedidentity-servername-rolenetbiosname/) comment on the problem. Also in this other  [Blog SystemMailbox](https://www.techieshelp.com/exchange-2013-update-rmssharedidentity-servername-rolenetbiosname/) and [Blog DiscoverySearchMailbox](https://www.techieshelp.com/exchange-2013-update-rmssharedidentity-servername-rolenetbiosname/)

```
Get-Mailbox -Arbitration | Format-Table Name, ServerName, Database -Auto
```

```
Get-Mailbox
```

Shows error of objects with server name that does not exist (mail-ex01 server that currently exists)

WARNING: The object contoso.com/Users/SystemMailbox
WARNING: The object contoso.com/Users/FederateMailbox
WARNING: The object contoso.com/Users/DiscoverySearchMailbox

has been corrupted and is in an incoherent state. The following validation errors have occurred:

| NAME | server Name |
| --- | --- |
| SystemMailbox{e0dc1c29-89c3-4034-b678-e6c29d823ed9} | mail-ex02 |
| SystemMailbox{1f05a927-43f2-4459-9ea1-31ee79fcf789} | mail-ex02 |
| FederatedEmail.4c1f4d8b-8179-4148-93bf-00a95fa1e042 | mail-ex02 |

| NAME | server Name |
| --- | --- |
| DiscoverySearchMailbox{D919BA05-46A6-415f-80AD-7E09334BB852} | mail-ex02 |

My query is, delete and recreate does not affect anything. Or fix registry attributes, which would be the most recommended.

Exchange 2010 (Mail-EX01) shows log of an old mail server with the name Mail-EX02.

Exchange 2010 (Mail-EX01 server that currently exists) is running smoothly with 100 users.

Comment: Exchange 2010 was off-topic years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now install exchange server 2016.
Following the next steps

1. On the domain server I delete the arbitration accounts of the following [tutorial](https://www.alitajran.com/recreate-arbitration-mailboxes-in-exchange-server/).
2. Uninstall exchange 2016 CU23

```
Setup.exe /Mode:Uninstall /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms_DiagnosticDataON
```

3. Check in IIS on Server for Exchange Server 2016, When uninstalling
   there is a temporary website, I delete the duplicate because it
   generates an error when reinstalling.
4. Restart the exchange server 2016 server.
5. Recreate the arbitration accounts, on the exchange server 2016
   server

```
setup.exe /PrepareAD /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms_DiagnosticDataON
```

```
Check on the domain server that the accounts are created.
```

6. I just installed the Exchange server 2016 CU23
7. Restart and test connection exchange 2016, Shell, Toolbox, ECP

---

Now I have a curiosity, the exchange 2016 installs without problem
When configuring for the migration I realize that only the mailbox role is installed.

```
   Get-ExchangeServer
```

> Exchange 2010   (Roles)-> MailBox, ClientAccess, HubTransport

> Exchange 2016   (Roles)-> Mailbox

I don't know if it is enabled later or if any problem occurred when installing exchange 2016

The idea is to migrate from Exchange 2010 to 2016 and then delete exchange 2010

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you may have posted the same question in the two communities, it seems that someone has answered it for you in Microsoft Q&A, you could refer to the Microsoft Q&A.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1337562/error-install-exchange-2016-coexistence-with-excha?comment=question#answers

Comment: Yes, [Ivan LV](https://serverfault.com/users/1021235/ivan-lv). I also posted on the Microsoft Q&A forums. Sorry if I'm missing any community forum rules. I am looking for help and every opinion is useful. I will be careful not to repeat the post.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with a similar error when installing Exchange 2019 in an Exchange 2013 environment. It ended up beeing due to RecipientFilterApplied was set to $false.

It was solved by a simple update of the EmailAddressPolicy:

```
Get-EmailAddressPolicy | Update-EmailAddressPolicy
```